# The bottom and right areas of canvas don't render

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

If I create a window with JFrame, several rows of pixels along the bottom and several columns along the right hand side are outside the window that is created so they don't show up. For example when I create a 800x600 window, the window will only show stuff in the top left 786x563 area. The amount that gets cut off also seems to vary with the size of the window. So far I've just manually adjusted the size and position of things. Currently in my code is set up like this:

```
import java.awt.*; //Canvas and Dimension
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = WIDTH/4*3; //800, 600
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    
    public Main() { //constructor
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game", this);
        requestFocus();
    }
    
    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }
    
    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 /amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames =0;
        while(running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+= (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta>=1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer+=1000;
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }
    
    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs==null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return; 
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //creates a line that should be 38 units above the bottom but instead is right along the bottom
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(1, 562, 30, 1);
        
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
        try{Thread.sleep(5);} catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }
}

class Window extends Canvas {
    public Window(int w, int h, String t, Main game) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(t);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

If I didn't include enough of my code to diagnose the problem please tell me so I can put the rest of it.

Comment: *"If I didn't include enough of my code to diagnose the problem please tell me so I can put the rest of it."* -- you can *and should* test your posted code yourself -- does it compile? does it reproduce the problem? No to both. We don't want the "rest of your code" but we do desire a compilable and runnable smallest subset that reproduces the problem, a [mre].  Please read the link before replying since it will explain much.

Comment: Two issues with your code: 1) you have a class that implements Runnable and yet shows no `run()` method, likely the most important method for you and us, and 2) your class extends Canvas, and you shouldn't be mixing Swing and AWT components in this way.

Comment: Also, you should call `fame.pack();` before making it visible.

Comment: You should be using a drawing JPanel instead of a Canvas and the JFrame decorations take up some of the space.  If you want your drawing JPanel to be 800 x 600, use the setPreferredSize method of JPanel to make it so and pack the JFrame.  The JFrame decorations will take up some additional pixels in the width and height.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5)` ← Do you really need to draw 200 frames per second?

Comment: @VGR When I run the actual program it's about 60-70 fps.

Comment: I believe `thread.join();  running = false;`  should be `running = false; thread.join();`  otherwise `running` becomes false only after `thread` stops which is not what you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.